# What's the difference between using semget/semctl to use semaphores instead of using sem_init/post/wait?

Tags: c, semaphore

I'd like to know why i should use one or the other and which one is best practice.

I know their use is different but in my experience i have not found any advantage in using one instead of the other.

Are there any reason to avoid using an implementation (other than code readability)?

Answer (score 0):

Different API's from different versions of UNIX. `semctl` et al, are from System V, while `sem_init` et al, are POSIX.

While they can be used for the same thing, they are not compatible with each other. You can't mix `semctl` with `sem_post` for example.